# error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'c' used ,

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain this error and typedef char with array and the best scenario to implement the stack with array?

```
typedef char StackItemType;

class stack {

    public:
        stack(int size)
        {
            items = new StackItemType[size];
            maxstack = size;
            top = -1;
        }
        ~stack() {
            delete[] items;
        }
        bool isEmpty();
        bool isFull();
        bool push(char newitem);
        bool pop(char *stacktop);
    private:
        StackItemType *items;
        int top, maxstack;
    };

int main()
{
    StackItemType c ;
    stack stack(5);
    stack.push('a'); 
    stack.push('b');
    stack.push('c'); 
    cout << c;
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: "any one explain this error" - I don't thinks so, without a full example to reproduce the error

Comment: {
    StackItemType c ;
    stack stack(5);

    stack.push('a');
    stack.push('b');
    stack.push('c');

    cout << c;

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
   }

Comment: i tried to add the code but i get this error...... It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details

Comment: you never do anything with `c` but then call `std::cout << c;` and thats what the error is trying to tell you

Comment: When posting questions about build errors, please include the copy-pasted *full* and *complete* output of the build-log, in the body of the question. Also mark out, with a comment, where in the shown code you get the error.

Comment: Also, your question is *much* to broad, since you ask about two very different subjects at the same time (and the second one is to broad all by itself). Please try to keep it to one question at a time. If you have multiple questions, ask multiple questions.

Comment: Lastly, the error message you posted in the title (which should really be a short one-sentence summary of your problem) is quite clear. It says that the variable `c` is used without initialization, and indeed you don't initialize it anywhere before you attempt to print it. For that specific question there are hundreds if not thousands of duplicates here on Stack Overflow, not to mention all over the Internet.

Comment: And please note that uninitialized non-static local variables will have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) value, and using them uninitialized in C++ leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code your declare a variable `c`. Then the first thing you try to do with the variable is print it's value. But you have never given it a value so the compiler gives you an 'uninitialised local variable' error. That's what it means, you are trying to use the value of a variable before you have given the variable a value.

I'm guessing that you meant to give `c` the value of the top item on the stack. If so then you should have written this code

```
StackItemType c ;
stack stack(5);
stack.push('a'); 
stack.push('b');
stack.push('c'); 
stack.pop(&c); // <<--- new code here that gives c a value
cout << c;
cout << endl;
system("pause");
```